# For A-algebra B,$rank_{A_p}M_p$=$rank_{B_q}M_q$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, modules

Let φ:$A\rightarrow B$ be a A-algebra (commutative ring),and M is a module over B.

Now if $M_p$ is a free module over $A_p$ with rank $l$,

then $M_q$ is a free module over $B_q$ with same rank $l$?

(where $p \in SpecA$ and $q$ be a image of $p$ by Spec(φ) )

Answer (score 0):

This is false in general: take $A=K$  a field, $B=K[X]$, $Q$ an irreducible polynomial in $B$. Then $M=B/(Q)$ is a finite extension field of $K$, is free  as a $K$-vector space, and $M_Q=B_Q/QB_Q=B/Q$ is a torsion $B_Q$-module.

Comment: sorry,why$M⊗_AB_q=M_q$?

Comment: *I* am sorry: didn't motive=ce that $M$ was a $B$-module, not an $A$-module. I'll withdraw my answer. I ythink one needs conditions on $B$ for the assertion to be true.

Comment: @8Frog: I've replaced my answer with a counter-example.